# What are the various denial of service vectors on the Lightning Network?

Tags: lightning-network, attack

What are the various denial of service (DoS) vectors on the Lightning Network?

Answer (score 1):

This is a draft answer. Alternative answers (as always) are welcome.

Alex Bosworth listed a number of DoS vectors on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/alexbosworth/status/1487817891143630849?s=20&t=9-7_WQKrAi8qrsMGPqwxCA). This isn't necessarily an exhaustive list.

- TCP level flooding
- P2P protocol flood
- Too-many graph updates
- Huge unsettled HTLCs
- Many slow HTLCs
- Pathfinding distraction
- RBF pinning
- 0-Base PPM floor HTLCs
- Many channel open proposals
- Fake Neutrino data
- KeySend spam